# I am trying to plot a regression in r studio and can not figure it out

Tags: r, plot, regression

Does anyone know how to plot a regression in r studio? Does anyone have a template of some sort of the code to plot this?

Comment: Can you say more about what you want to plot? For example, residuals, predictions, coefficients, etc. What type of regression: Continuous outcome, categorical outcome, etc.? It will also help us help you if you provide a [reproducible example](https://community.rstudio.com/t/faq-whats-a-reproducible-example-reprex-and-how-do-i-do-one/5219).

Comment: For some canned functions for visualizing regressions, see, for example, the following packages: [`visreg`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/visreg/vignettes/quick-start.html), [`jtools`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/jtools/vignettes/summ.html#summ), and [`finalfit`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/finalfit/vignettes/finalfit.html).

Comment: if possible, you should say more about what you've tried so far to solve your problem ...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
x <- rnorm(1000,20,10)
y <- x+rnorm(1000, 10, 5)
plot(x, y, col="green")
abline(lm(y~x), col="blue")
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it easy:

```
plot ( x , y )
```

x = independent variable , 
y = dependent variable